# Gson returns Json object with `=` instead of `:`

Tags: java, json, gson

Here is my code:

```
assertEquals(
    gson.fromJson("[{\"vehicle_side\":\"driver\",\"vehicle_occupant_role\":\"driver\",\"vehicle_window\":\"front_right\",\"window_status\":10.0}]", List.class),           
    gson.fromJson(myJsonObject, List.class)
);
```

The assertion fails because:

```
Expected :[{vehicle_window=front_right, vehicle_occupant_role=driver, window_status=10.0, vehicle_side=driver}]
Actual   :[{"vehicle_side":"driver","vehicle_occupant_role":"driver","vehicle_window":"front_right","window_status":10.0}]
```

Why does my expected object contain `=` instead of `:`?
I even tried it with the actual json string hardcoded, but I get the same result:

Comment: *"Why does my expected object contain `=`"* ... that's how maps are printed via `toString()`.

Comment: probably one is your json, the other one is the `toString`

Comment: `gson.fromJson()` is converting things _away from JSON_, so it's no surprise when they're no longer serialized in JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `toString()` is mapping `':'` to `'='`. To resolve this, use get the `jsonString` from `myJsonObject` and pass it to `gson.fromJson()`. You can use ObjectMapper for this, or Gson itself.

with objectMapper:

```
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myJsonObject);
```

with Gson:

```
gson.toJson(myJsonObject);
```